# Extract values from a vector and sort them based on their original squence

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector

I have a vector of numbers (temperatures), and I am using the MATLAB function `mink` to extract the 5 smallest numbers from the vector to form a new variable. However, the numbers extracted using `mink` are automatically ordered from lowest to largest (of those 5 numbers). Ideally, I would like to retain the sequence of the numbers as they are arranged in the original vector. I hope my problem is easy to understand. I appreciate any advice.

Comment: `[values, indices] = mink(array)` -> reorder using indices.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am already using that bit of code which you provided. However, my issue is in reordering the "extracted" values using the indices. For example, the five values "extracted" using mink are 13,14,15,16,17 and their corresponding indices from the source vector are 6,7,5,4,3. The source vector is a 24 x 1 column vector, from which the minimum numbers are extracted. I want to order/sort them according to their sequence in the source vector, rather than the ascending order which mink imposes. Can that be done? Thanks btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`mink`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mink.html) that you use was introduced in MATLAB 2017b. It has ([as Andras Deak mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867776/matlab-extract-values-from-a-vector-and-sort-them-based-on-their-original-squen#comment90687403_51867776)) two output arguments:

```
[B,I] = mink(A,k);
```

The second output argument are the indices, such that `B == A(I)`.

To obtain the set `B` but sorted as they appear in `A`, simply sort the vector of indices `I`:

```
B = A(sort(I));
```

For example:

```
>> A = [5,7,3,1,9,4,6];
>> [~,I] = mink(A,3);
>> A(sort(I))
ans =
     3     1     4
```

For older versions of MATLAB, it is possible to reproduce `mink` using `sort`:

```
function [B,I] = mink(A,k)
  [B,I] = sort(A);
  B = B(1:k);
  I = I(1:k);
```

Note that, in the above, you don't need the `B` output, your `ordered_mink` can be written as follows

```
function B = ordered_mink(A,k)
  [~,I] = sort(A);
  B = A(sort(I(1:k)));
```

**Note:** This solution assumes `A` is a vector. For matrix `A`, see [Andras' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51873806/7328782), which he wrote up at the same time as this one.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to achieve - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need the corresponding indices for the extracted values from `mink` using its two-output form:

```
[vals, inds] = mink(array);
```

Then you only need to order the items in `val` according to increasing indices in `inds`. There are multiple ways to do this, but they all revolve around sorting `inds` and using the corresponding order on `vals`. The simplest way is to put these vectors into a matrix and sort the rows:

```
sorted_rows = sortrows([inds, vals]); % sort on indices
```

and then just extract the corresponding column

```
reordered_vals = sorted_rows(:,2); % items now ordered as they appear in "array"
```

A less straightforward possibility for doing the sorting after the above call to `mink` is to take the sorting order of `inds` and use its inverse to reverse-sort `vals`:

```
reverse_inds = inds; % just allocation, really
reverse_inds(inds) = 1:numel(inds); % contruct reverse permutation
reordered_vals = vals(reverse_inds); % should be the same as previously
```